# MYSQL Multiple table optimization for advanced search

Tags: mysql, performance, index-tuning, myisam, eav, query-performance

I have a `users` table where there is the basic information of each user:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_type` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `registration_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `account_status` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

On the other hand, I have a `user_data' table in which we put every other data:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_data` (
  `data_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `value` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`data_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Basically, the data is stored as a `name` => `value`

I fetch the data in the following fashion:

```
SELECT email, ud_desc.value as description, ud_lang.value as language
    FROM users
        JOIN user_data as ud_desc
        ON ud_desc.user_id = users.user_id
            AND ud_desc.name = 'description'
        JOIN user_data as ud_lang
        ON ud_lang.user_id = users.user_id
            AND ud_lang.name = 'language'
```

I made that second table this way because there is a ton of different data for each user, certain depending on their `users.account_type`.
Also my client keeps adding, removing and changing different kinds of data all the time.
So I needed something quite flexible and this is the best idea I came up with so far, from a developer point of view. Because I fear that this so called "best idea" is just a faint dream and will be too slow on the long term.

Knowing that I might have to perform `LIKE` and `MATCH AGAINST` queries on the large volume of data that `user_data` will hold.

Also, you might take note that I am not very familiar with indexes. But at this point, I have no idea what is the most efficient, given that the data is fetch based on two columns `user_data.user_id` and `user_data.name`.

Should I make both of those columns (`user_id` and `name`) indexes? Should `user_id` be a foreign key (for the `users` table JOIN)?

Is there a way to improve either my database model or my queries?

I thank you all in advance. I am a bit lost at the moment and need some fresh points of view on this matter. Don't hesitate to tell me if you need more details.

Comment: "Should user_id be a foreign key": Not for making something faster but, yes, that's a good idea in general. (And as MySQL creates an index on a foreign key, it maybe even speed up some queries.)

Answer (score 0):

- Don't use MyISAM, use InnoDB.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb
- EAV is inefficient, especially when you normalize either of the columns.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav  And read more about Entity-Attribute-Value schemas in stackoverflow.com
- You are missing some critical indexes that are critical to performance.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta
- At this point, `FOREIGN KEYs` are the least of the issues.